# Image is not coming in center with applying the css to it

Tags: html, css, asp.net

i want to make image in center but not able to do it
my aspx code is

```
 <figure class="centercarosal">
   <img src="UImages/<%#Eval("Logo") %>" style="height: 100px" alt="">
 </figure>
```

and the class for centercarosal is

```
.centercarosal{
text-align:center!important
}
```

Comment: `center !important;`

Comment: This should have worked perfectly may be there's a conflict between CSS due to which some other CSS is overriding  `.centercarosal` effect. Go to developer console and focus at this element and see which CSS class is creating trouble. Try to override it and avoid using `!important` as it will trouble you in implementing new changes.

Comment: Is the semi-colon just missing in the question, or is it actually missing in your code?

Comment: its just missing here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the browser specification for both please try this

```
.centercarosal {
    text-align: -moz-center;
}
```